# Taking limit of a power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

It is known that the $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ converges for all $0 < x \leq M$. Let $f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ for $x \in (0,M]$. Is it true that

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = a_0?$$

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\text{ converges for all }x\in (-M,M].$$ Also, $f:(-M,M]\to\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n, \ x\in (-M,M]$ is continuous on $(-M,M]$.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the hint! Please confirm my answer:

Since $f$ you mentioned is continuous, then $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0)$. Then, we get what I wanted to prove.

Comment: Just as information: There is no guarantee that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(-M)^n$ will converge, for example, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}x^n, -1<x\leq 1.$

Comment: Yes, you are right. $\lim_{x\to 0+}f(x)=a_0$.

Comment: See also this: [Abel's Limit Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925758/intuitive-explanation-of-proof-of-abels-limit-theorem?rq=1)